# Intellisense - deduce right Class by its methods

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm used to work with NetBeans and now I'm trying IntelliJ. So my question is: Does IntelliJ has a way to get right class by its methods?

For example, in NetBeans if I write:

```
glGenBu // Intellisense will kick in and will suggest me 
           to use GL15.glGenBuffers() method from GL15 class
```

This will automatically import the right library.

This is very handy because I'm working with LWJGL and it has a bad way to manage OpenGL methods ('GLXX' where XX is the version of OpenGL and all methods that appeared in that version are stored in that class) and I never remember the right class where my desired method is.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressing `Ctrl+Space` when you already see completion list will show more suggestions, with static methods from the entire project among them. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-completing-code.html for more details.

Comment: A singe CTRL+SPACE does not work, but a CTRL+(double tap)SPACE does the job. Thank you.